# What is behind the "message redacted" in "Chiron Beta Prime" by Jonathan Coulton

Tags: lyrics, indie

So there is this song, [Chiron Beta Prime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3DyxaCYlfg) by Jonathan Coulton, where he tells the story of a family that is on a mining asteroid Chiron Beta Prime and working for the robots there. It is written as a letter for christmas to a relative. And there is a point where there is "message redacted" spoken over the track. Is there a "canon" text, that belongs there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love Jonathan Coulton and this is an interesting question. However, I think this is just regular Coulton humour.

The family is obviously forced by the robots to stay and work on the asteroid, that's what [the lyrics](https://wiki.jonathancoulton.com/Chiron_Beta_Prime/Lyrics) are all about:

> Merry Christmas from Chiron Beta Prime,
>   Where we're working in a mine for our robot overlords.
>   Did I say overlords? I meant protectors.
>   Merry Christmas from Chiron Beta Prime.

The robots are apparently redacting the message preventing the family to send out a "hidden" emergency message:

> That's all the family news that we're allowed to talk about.
>   We really hope you'll come and visit us soon.
>   I mean we're literally begging you to visit us.
>   And make it quick before they [MESSAGE REDACTED].

The above lyrics snippets are from the official lyrics site, and I highly doubt that there are any "hidden" lyrics behind it. After all, *MESSAGE REDACTED* is part of the lyrics.

Answer (score 0):

It's not canon, but I've always suspected it's "blow up the moon". It rhymes, it fits the meter and it also fits the theme very well.

> That's all the family news that we're allowed to talk about.
> We really hope you'll come and visit us soon.
> I mean we're literally begging you to visit us.
> And make it quick before they **blow up the moon**

But, as the accepted answer points out, the words [MESSAGE REDACTED] are the *actual* lyrics and the idea that they failed to get the message out is funnier than anything that could be there instead.

Answer (score 0):

"Before they send us to the Moon" which scans as well as rhymes. Assuming the Moon is a scrapyard where there will be no more Andersons